# HASHTAG HARDSHIPS - How to Open a Menu Dropdown WITHOUT hashtag being placed in URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, hashtag

So here is my issue. Say I have a menu bar that is supposed to become a dropdown when the user taps on it via a mobile device. Say that I also hate when the # symbol appears after my url when I click on said menu (www.google.com/# for example) I've been able to use the "animate scroll" javascript that allows me to smoothly scroll the site to an anchortag, which also hides the # symbol. But for some reason I am having issues trying to get my menu to open on small screens!

Here is the menu html

```
<div class=navmover>
    <nav id="effect" class="newClass">
        <ul>
            <li id="mobibutton" class="lightupmobi">
                <a href="#" id="button">
                    <div style="display:block !important;position:relative !important;top:8px !important;padding-left:0.5em !important;right:3px !important;text-align:left !important;">MENU</div>
                    <img id="mobibutton" src="images/nav-icon.png" style="position:relative !important;left:40% !important;">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="hideme" class="lightup">
                <a id=link1 href=#intro>Top</a>
            </li>
            <li id="hideme" class="lightup">
                <a id=link2 href=#work>Work</a>
            </li>
            <li id="hideme" class="lightup">
                <a id=link3 href=#services>Services</a>
            </li>
            <li id="hideme" class="lightup">
                <a id=link4 href=#about>About</a>
            </li>
            <li id="hideme" class="lightup">
                <a id=link5 href=#contact>Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

javascript used to open and close menu

```
<!--Show Hide Button JS-->
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#button1").click(function() {
            $("#effect").toggleClass("newClass", 1000);
            $("li").toggleClass("showme", 1000);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

javascript used to smoothly scroll between anchors

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#link1").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});
        $("#link2").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});
        $("#link3").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});
        $("#link4").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});
        $("#link5").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});
        $("#link6").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});
        $("#link7").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});
    });
</script>

<script type=text/javascript>
    function scrollTo(b) {
        var a=$(b).offset().top;
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:a},"slow");
    }
</script>
```

Rest of the javascript in the site. Apologies... I realize it is a ton to look at.

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/kmaxx7p4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script async src=javascripts/svg.js></script>
<script src=javascripts/jquery.js></script>
<script src=http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js></script>
<script src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js></script>
<script src=javascripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js></script>
<script src=javascripts/jquery.animate.js type=text/javascript></script>
<script src=javascripts/jquery.scrollanchor.js type=text/javascript></script>
<script src=javascripts/jquery.sticky.js type=text/javascript></script>
<script async src=javascripts/jquery.inview.js type=text/javascript></script>
<script async src=javascripts/jquery.flexslider.js type=text/javascript></script>
<script async src=javascripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js type=text/javascript></script>
<script src=http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript>function ReplaceContentInContainer(c,b){var a=document.getElementById(c);a.innerHTML=b}</script>
<script type=text/javascript>function preload(a){$(a).each(function(){$("<img/>")[0].src=this})}preload(["images/bg.png","images/cloudscape2.png","images/logo2.svg","images/logo2.png",]);</script>
<script>$(function(){$(".two").css("opacity",0).fadeTo(0,0);$(".one").on("mouseenter mouseleave",function(a){var b=a.type=="mouseenter"?$(".two",this).stop().fadeTo(200,1):$(".two",this).stop().fadeTo(200,0)})});</script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("nav").sticky({topSpacing:0})});</script>
<script type=text/javascript>$(document).ready(function(){$("#link1").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});$("#link2").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});$("#link3").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});$("#link4").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});$("#link5").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});$("#link6").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});$("#link7").anchorScroll({fx:"easeInOutExpo"});});</script>
<script type=text/javascript>function scrollTo(b){var a=$(b).offset().top;$("html,body").animate({scrollTop:a},"slow");}</script>
<script>$(window).load(function(){$(".flexslider").flexslider({animation:"slide",slideshow:true,slideshowSpeed:3500,animationSpeed:1000})});</script>
<script type=text/javascript charset=utf-8>$(document).ready(function(){$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({social_tools:false,theme:"light_square"})});</script>
```

If push comes to shove I can also give the link to my website so you can see for yourself on your phone/tablet and see the issue I'm having. Let me know if I'm being too vague and you guys need more info as well. Please help and thank you!

Comment: did you test to see if the click event is even happening? figure out what the actual problem is. the `return false` is enough to stop the default behavior of a click, unless the event being triggered isn't a click event.

Comment: There is supposed to be two click events essentially. One when you click on Menu and also on the menu button. Clicking on either of these should open the menu. With the return false in place it seems to interfere with these links somehow.. I'm trying to pin point how that's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `#` as your `href` value.  There are lots of different ways to "target nothing" like you are trying to do, including:

- using `event.preventDefault()` in the code that is bound to your event, to ignore the default link behavior
- using `return false;` at the end of the code that is bound to your event, to interrupt any further processing of the event all together
- using `href="javascript: void(0);"` as the target of your `<a>` tag, to make the target "do nothing"

. . . and there are other variations, depending on the situation (e.g., `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from triggering on all of an elements ancestors, not the current element).

Personally, in this particular case, I would go the `href="javascript: void(0);"` route myself, but you have some wiggle room to work with, to come up with the approach that you prefer.

---

**Update:** Come to think of it, is there a reason why you are using an `<a>` tag to begin with (e.g., styling reasons)?  You could simply bind the click on the `<li>` instead and remove the link behavior from the equation all together . . .

Comment: Excuse the trolls.... And thank you guys greatly for the quick responses! Anyway there is no reason why I have the menu as a "href link" other than I wanted the menu to be clickable. I will give it a try with the suggestions you've made and get back with you! :D

Answer (score 0):

You colud run a scroll function that does what you wish

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a hashtag because you don't want it to go to the top of the page, just use an empty javascript: URL.

```
<a href="javascript:">Link does nothing, tada</a>
```

Comment: This is bad practice. `event.preventDefault()` and `onclick="return false"` exist for that purpose.

Comment: The OP said his onClick event was already in use. The question was how to make a href link target nothing without using a hashtag. Your solution would use onClick, which is not what the OP is asking, and simply setting href to nothing would link to the folder the current file is contained in. I realize javascript: is outdated and for good reason, but this is the only solution that comes to mind without onClick atm.